# Is this sentence still used or is it outdated/archaic?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expression

I found this sentence on Duolingo, the English and German are as follows:

"Which name does it bear?"
"Welchen Namen trägt es?"

Is it still used and if yes, in what context? I believe this is supposed to mean "What is its name" or "What is it called".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, „den Namen ... tragen“ is still used (not that commonly, however). I suppose one would say „Wie heißt es?“ in the most cases.

Comment: @infinitezero Done! :)

Answer (score 3):

Your question is about the use of "einen / den Namen tragen". It depends on the context. As a question it is probably outdated and one would use

> Wie heißt es?

> Welchen Namen hat es?

However, it is still used in a formal context like

> Die  Israelitische  Kultusgemeinde  Wien  hat  deshalb  bereits  im  Jahr  2002   gemeinsam   mit   zahlreichen   namhaften   Institutionen   die   Initiative   ergriffen,   ein   internationales  Shoah-Forschungszentrum  in  Wien  zu  errichten,  das  den  Namen  Simon  Wiesenthals  tragen  soll. [... ]
> Daher  habe  ich auch zugestimmt, dass das Forschungszentrum meinen
> Namen tragen soll.

> Graz: Arnie gibt Ehrenring zurück
> (st) - Arnold Schwarzenegger, Gouverneur von Kalifornien und Namensgeber für das Grazer Fußball-Stadion, ist jetzt zum Angriff übergegangen. Schwarzenegger hat erklärt, dass das Stadion nicht weiter seinen Namen tragen soll.
> [2](https://www.perlentaucher.de/medienticker-archiv/2005-12-20.html)

Comment: @infinitezero Done ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's still used in the context you mentioned.

Comment: Is it too formal or used casually?

Comment: Suppose your name is Churchill, in this case you still would say: "Ich trage den Namen Churchill.", because it's not only a name you have, but in some sense maybe also a burden to carry.

Comment: Currently this question has three answers but no upvotes. If you think it is worth your time answering it, please consider upvotes as well.

Comment: @Feiznia Its not really formal formal, but it certainly isn't slang. It is Hochdeutsch and it is used commonly in some circles and it will not make you look strange or bad or even nerdy. Just somewhat "gebildet"